# Chrome Dev tools: Couldn't see request's FormData during breakpoint, but it clearly existed when sent

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

When visiting https://myedit.online/en/audio-editor/ai-sound-effect-generator, I am trying to reverse engineer the initial request to https://myedit.online/tsfx/effect. After investigation, my hypothesis is that the request is sending a CryptoKey to the server so they can sync on what kind of URL the server should expect next. The obfuscated logic of requiring a specific key in the URL for every generation prevents people from using the API without running the browser code.

I saw that in the first request to https://myedit.online/tsfx/effect, there's a payload with "receipt", "key", and "timestamp": [image]

I clicked on "Initiator" to find out where in .js code the request originated. It takes me to an obfuscated function `c.send(i || null)`.

When I set a breakpoint here and reproduce the circumstances for it to call https://myedit.online/tsfx/effect, I can see the expected URL in the request: [image]

However, no matter where I looked, whether in surrounding local variables or in the `XMLHttpRequest` object, all the `FormData` were empty: [image]

When I resumed running the code, it made the call successfully and I observed the payload as shown in the 1st screenshot again. So it has to be that line of code, but somehow the form data is not showing up. Where would I be able to find it?

Comment: Devtools doesn't show complex objects like FormData. You can add a watch for `[...i]` or `Object.fromEntries(i)` for more convenient display.

Comment: What makes you assume that the form data object is empty?

Comment: @Bergi How do I read it properly? I checked every field it could've been in; I would've thought at least "keys" or "values" would have a length of more than 0

Comment: @wOxxOm Thank you; does that mean I would need to modify the .js and make the website run the modified file? Also, what determines how complex an object is before Devtools can't show it anymore?

Comment: @pete The `values` in the screenshot is just showing the function object which has a [`length` of 0](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/length), i.e. `formData.values()` is not taking any arguments. But you'll have to actually call it to see the values it returns - like woxxom suggested. Unlike a normal `Map`, the `FormData` unfortunately has no `.size` that you could inspect. Like other builtin objects, the devtools might be able to show its internals like *[[entries]]*, but it appears they don't :-/

Comment: @pete, no, add my code as a watch in devtools or type it in console.